# how to can i access data from array to use it in method

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, methods

Once you have got all user inputs and stored it in the respective arrays, it’s time to
create a static method named calculateTax() that accepts two parameters
1. String name
2. long income
 Within calculateTax() method, write code using IF-ELSE-IF conditional statements
to calculate the tax keeping in mind the following aspects
1. If the income is greater than or equal to 3 lacs per annum then the person is
liable to pay 20% of his income as tax
2. If the income is greater than or equal to 1 lac per annum but smaller than 3 lacs
per annum then the person is liable to pay 10% of his income as tax
3. If the income is smaller than 1 lac per annum then the person is exempted from
paying tax

// this is code till now
package com.internshala.javaapp;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
// TAX calculator app
    System.out.println("Tax Calculator App");
    System.out.println("------WELCOME------");

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter total person count:");
    int person = scanner.nextInt();

    String[] names = new String[person];
    long [] incomes = new long[person];


    for(int i=0;i<names.length;i++) {
        scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter name "+(i+1)+":");
        names[i]=scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter "+names[i]+"'s Annual income");
        incomes[i]=scanner.nextLong();
    }
    calculateTax(names:names[],incomes:incomes[]);

}
public static void calculateTax(String[] names , long[] incomes){

}
```

}

Comment: What have you tried? What specifically do you need help with?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because: ["3. Questions asking for homework help ***must*** include a **summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem**, and a **description of the difficulty you are having** solving it."](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Current state of your question doesn't fulfill these requirements. Use [edit] option to improve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(int i=0;i<names.length;i++) {
        scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter name "+ (i+1));
        names[i] =  scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter "+ names[i] + "'s Annual income");
        incomes[i] = scanner.nextLong();
}
```

This should help you.

Comment: "Tax Calculator App
------WELCOME------
Enter total person count:
3
Enter name01
Enter's Annual income "

Comment: add the scanner.nextLine() before loop

Comment: This is because scanner.nextInt() we use to get no of students, stays in the same line and is reading from same line for nextLine().So adding scanner.nextLine() will definitely make it work.

Comment: Tax Calculator App
------WELCOME------
Enter total person count:
3
Enter name01
amit
Enter amit's Annual income
156348
Enter name11
Enter 's Annual income  //ITS TAKING ONLY FIRST NAME

Comment: Adding scanner.nextLine() inside the loop gives right answer

Comment: I have edited the code,The issue came because we are again using nextLong and it is staying in same line and not reading from next line.I hope this should work.I tried it. @AMITKumar Please try this out and tell me

Comment: Yeah it's running totally fine thank you. and is it compulsion to write "Enter name"+i+1 bcoz it showing enter name 01 then 11 , 21 acc. to loop

Comment: yeah for that you can give (i+1) in brackets this will give as 1,2, etc

Comment: System.out.println("Enter name 1:"+(i+1));  like this??

Comment: No.System.out.println("Enter name "+(i+1)+":"); like this

Comment: can you help me in this another problem??

Comment: Yes..I can help